# Chain promises calls

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise

I need a consecutive execution of these three

```
return App.initAccount().then(App.bindEvents).then(App.render);
```

whereas App.initAccount():

```
  initAccount: async function() {

    console.log('Initializing account...');

    await web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err !== null) {
        throw err;
      }

      App.account = account;
      console.log('Account: ' + App.account);
    });
  }
```

and App.bindEvents(), App.render() just ordinary synchronous functions.
But what I've got in a console:

```
Initializing account...
Binding events
Rendering
Account: ***
```

Please, explain, how to chain these calls in order to wait until the asynchronous function is returned

UPD. According to the documentation I thought web3.eth.getCoinbase() returns a Promise<\String>, but turned out that wasn't correct.

Comment: The way you're doing it is okay as far as one can tell from the question, although 1. It's odd (perhaps wrong) to treat `web3.eth.getCoinbase` as though it returns a promise *and* provide a callback, and 2. if `bindEvents` and `render` do their work synchronously, you'd usually put them in the same `then` handler. Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose `web3.eth.getCoinbase()` does not return a promise (so you are not awaiting anything here. You need to wrap the function call in a promise like this :

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err !== null) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      App.account = account;
      return resolve(account)
    });
})
```

### Edit based on T.J suggestion

In this case, you don't actually need `initAccount` to be an asynchronous function, you can refactor your function to be :

```
initAccount: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Initializing account...');

    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err !== null) {
        return reject(err)
      }

      App.account = account;
      console.log('Account: ' + App.account);
      return resolve(account)
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Yep that's completely true :)

Answer (score 1):

From a style standpoint, you're best off not mixing callbacks and async/await in terms of sequential flow. To use callback style functions and weave them in with async/await, you can wrap them in promises to "hide" the promises away:

```
class Foo {
    initAccount() {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
                if (err !== null) {
                    reject(err);
                }
                resolve(account);
            });
        });
    }
}

const o = new Foo();
const account = await foo.initAccount();
// Then do bindEvents
// etc
```

Comment: *"You're best off not mixing promises and async/await in terms of sequential flow."* In this particular case, yeah.

Comment: I'd say in most cases. It would be somewhat jarring to see something like: `const value = await foo(); somethingElse(value).then(....);`

Comment: Jarring and something to flag on a code review. :-) But using `Promise.all` within an `async` function isn't uncommon at all, and `Promise.resolve`, `Promise.reject`, and `Promise.race` can usefully appear as well.

Comment: Agreed. I guess I should have been more specific to say "mixing async/await and callbacks".

Answer (score 0):

`getCoinbase` does not look like a function returning a promise. You should wrap it to behave as expected.

Either manually:

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
    if (err !== null) {
      reject(err);
    }

    App.account = account;
    console.log('Account: ' + App.account);
    resolve(account);
  });
});
```

Or using something like [this](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `web3.eth.getCoinbase` doesn't return a promise, since you're passing a callback to it. `await` only awaits *promises*.

So you probably need to wrap that API in a promise, which means that `initAccount` wouldn't need to be an `async` function as this is one of the rare situations where you need `new Promise`:

```
initAccount: function() {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    console.log('Initializing account...');

    web3.eth.getCoinbase(function(err, account) {
      if (err !== null) {
        reject(err);
      } else {
        App.account = account;
        console.log('Account: ' + App.account);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Separately, if `bindEvents` and `render` do their work synchronously, you'd usually put them in the same `then` handler:

```
return App.initAccount().then(() => {
  App.bindEvents();
  App.render();
});
```